# fetch request results won't let me make a string of an index

Tags: arrays, nsfetchrequest

Im getting a fetch request into an array. When i try and take the first index and make it into a string, the application crashes. any idea why it would do this?

```
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let frequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Round")

    let sortDesc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "course", ascending: true)

    frequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]

    var fetchedArray:Array = context.executeFetchRequest(frequest, error: nil)


    var myString:String = fetchedArray[0] as String



    println(myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to convert my primitives to objects. The code below works

```
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let frequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Round")

    let sortDesc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "course", ascending: true)

    frequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc]


    var fetchedArray:Array = context.executeFetchRequest(frequest, error: nil)
    var myString:Array = (fetchedArray as NSArray).valueForKeyPath("course") as NSArray

    self.navigationItem.title = myString[0] as NSString
```